# Android studio request to install build tool although build tool has been install

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I got the issue when I open an Android application that download from Github.

Android studio shows the message " Error:[installPlatformSDK] build tools version 24.0.0 is not installed in SDK. ".
I checked in SDK/build tool: The build tool version has been installed.

You can check the image: 
[image]

Do you have any suggestion to resolve this problem ?
Thank in advance.

Comment: can you show your gradle file?

Comment: Check if `local.properties` has `sdk.dir` set to the correct location

Comment: @akash93: sdk.dir=E\:\\Android\\Android_Studio_SDK : Correct location.

Comment: @AnandJain: My friend open the same project, he didn't get the same problem. So I though the gradle file is fine.

Comment: It seems like a sdk linking issue.. Try deleting the build tools from the sdk manager and installing them using the `Fix ..` hint which comes when the project build fails

Comment: @akash93: your solution can't resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem.

1. Add stacktrace log:
   File/Setting/Build, Execution, Deployment/Debugger/Compiler add "--stacktrace --info" to get gradle build log.
2. The log shows that: 
   16:10:11.077 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':app:installPlatformSDK'.
   16:10:11.077 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Task] Error : [installPlatformSDK] build tools version 24.0.0 is not installed in SDK.
   16:10:11.077 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Task] tool path : E:\Android\Android_Studio_SDK;/build-tools/24.0.0

So I change ANDROID_HOME from: "

> E:\Android\Android_Studio_SDK;

" to "

> E:\Android\Android_Studio_SDK

"
3. Restart the computer and rebuild project.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Inccorect ANDROID_HOME value:

```
C:\Users\sev_user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Correct sdk value:

```
C:\Users\sev_user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

=> Different: Sdk and sdk.

after I changed to the correct value, it built and installed apk successfully.